# java timer - how to scheduletask at a particular time in the future

Tags: java, timer, schedule

I have used java.util.Timer to schedule TimerTask to be run every 2 hours .

But how do I schedule a task to run say everynight at 2 am ?

This might be something easy, I am just overlooking something I guess.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) scheduling system with a `CronTrigger`.

Answer (score 1):

Call

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, twoAmDate, twentyFourHoursInMillis )
```

on java.util.Timer

Comment: Yes, see http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask, java.util.Date, long)